# Give these error twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

It will give the error of `twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet` I will use `download_delay` in setting   but some time they work and  give output but sometime they do not work I want a permanent solution how I avoid these error `twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet` is there any solution for it kindly share it I am searching but not find any appropiate solution  these is page link https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.http import Request


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    url = 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php'
    cookies = {
    'CAKEPHP': 'u6u40lefkqnm45j49a5i0h6bs3',
    '__utma': '42336182.871903078.1657200864.1657200864.1657200864.1',
    '__utmz': '42336182.1657200864.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
    }

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
        # 'Cookie': 'CAKEPHP=u6u40lefkqnm45j49a5i0h6bs3; __utma=42336182.871903078.1657200864.1657200864.1657200864.1; __utmz=42336182.1657200864.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
        'Origin': 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com',
        'Referer': 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    }

    formdata = [
        ('tuusan_year', ''),
        ('tuusan_month', ''),
        ('tuusan_chk', ''),
        ('methodAndOr1', ''),
        ('methodAndOr2', ''),
        ('methodAndOr3', ''),
        ('text_sen', ''),
        ('text_skill', ''),
        ('text_business', ''),
        ('tokkyo_data', ''),
        ('fuki_day_chk', ''),
        ('shuju', ''),
        ('kensyuu_bunya', ''),
        ('text_kensyuu', ''),
        ('methodAndOr_kensyuu', ''),
        ('keitai_kikan', ''),
        ('keitai_hisu', ''),
        ('display_flag', '1'),
        ('search', '2'),
        ('text', ''),
        ('method', ''),
        ('methodAndOr', ''),
        ('area', ''),
        ('pref', ''),
        ('name', ''),
        ('kana', ''),
        ('id', ''),
        ('year', ''),
        ('month', ''),
        ('day', ''),
        ('day_chk', ''),
        ('exp01', ''),
        ('exp02', ''),
        ('exp03', ''),
        ('trip', ''),
        ('venture_support', ''),
        ('venture_flag', ''),
        ('university_support', ''),
        ('university_flag', ''),
        ('university1', ''),
        ('university2', ''),
        ('university', ''),
        ('college', ''),
        ('high_pref', ''),
        ('junior_pref', ''),
        ('elementary_pref', ''),
        ('tyosaku', ''),
        ('hp', ''),
        ('jukoureki', ''),
        ('experience1', ''),
        ('experience2', ''),
        ('experience3', ''),
        ('experience4', ''),
        ('sort', ''),
        ('fuki_year', ''),
        ('fuki_month', ''),
        ('fuki_day', ''),
        ('fuki_day_chk', ''),
        ('id_chk', ''),
        ('shugyou', ''),
        ('fuki', ''),
        ('address1', ''),
        ('address2', ''),
        ('trip_pref', ''),
        ('expref', ''),
        ('office', ''),
        ('max_count', '1438'),
        ('search_count', '1438'),
        ('start_count', '1'),
        ('search_default', '1000'),
    ]
   
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            url=self.url,
            method='POST',
            formdata=self.formdata,
            cookies=self.cookies,
            headers=self.headers,
            callback=self.parse_item,
            )
        
        
    def parse_item(self, response):
        base_url="https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/"
        links =response.xpath("//table[4]//tr")
        for link in links[1:]:
            t=link.xpath("//form//@action").get()
            u=link.xpath(".//input[@name='serial']//@value").get()
            product=base_url+t+"?serial="+u+"&office_serial=&submit2=Details"
            yield Request(product,callback=self.parse_book)
                    
    def parse_book(self,response):
        name=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Name')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
                
        telephone=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'TEL')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
        
        fax=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'FAX')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
        
        email=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Email')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
        
        website=response.xpath("//td[text()[contains(.,'Website')]]/following-sibling::td//a[starts-with(@href, 'http')]/@href").get()
        
        
        registration_date=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Registration date')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
        
        
        firm=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Firm Name')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
        
        
        address=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Address (Prefecture)')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
        
        
        
        spec=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Specialization')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get().replace(" ï½œ","|")
        
        
        tech=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Technical field')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get().replace(" ï½œ","|")
        
        
        yield{
        "name":name,
        "Telephone":telephone,
        "Fax":fax,
        "Email":email,
        "website":website,
        "Registration_date":registration_date,
        "Firm_name":firm,
        "Address":address,
        "Specialization":spec,
        "Technical_field":tech
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the full error output?

Comment: these is error 
`2022-07-09 01:49:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_3.php?serial=19&office_serial=&submit2=Details> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]`

Comment: I have tested your code and it works but I eventually get the same error also. It's probably a server issue and you're getting blocked.

Comment: Is there solution they we avoid the blockage